Extract and sum all numbers before semicolons in string
I have a list of different categories of printing and would like to enter any date on which a printout was done and how many pages were printed, thus:



Produkt
Dato
Pris




A4 s/k éi
4.5.2024: 1;
−£  0,41


A4 s/k to
1.5.2024: 1; 4.5.2024: 9; 5.5.2024: 4
−£  0,26


A4 farge éi

£  0,00


A4 farge to
4.5.2024: 2;
−£ 10,09


A4 s/k éi, fin

£  0,00


A4 s/k to, fin

£  0,00


A4 farge éi, fin

£  0,00


A4 farge to, fin

£  0,00


Bibliotek, per

£  0,00


Blekk

£  0,00


Tonar

£  0,00



Let us call the columns A, B and C. In column A is the kind of printing cost; in column B is the date and the number of printouts; in column C is a VLOOKUP which gathers the page cost for each type of printout and multiplies that by the number in column B.
Column B is always in the format d.m.yyyy: x; where x is the number of pages. The date and month can be two digits.
What I would like to do, is find some way to extract all column B numbers that are between the colon and semicolon, add them together and multiply them by the VLOOKUP value in C. Is there any way to do that in Calc? I have so far only found one way to do this that works well with one instance: TEXTBEFORE, though I do not think that formula even exists in Calc, and in any case it only works for a single case. How can this be solved?
Main question: How can I extract each number between the colon and semicolon and sum them all?
P. S.: I currently have the following formula to extract the number of colons and multiply them by the price; this is the closest I have gotten:
=IF(D56="";"";(LEN(E56)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E56;":";"")))*VLOOKUP(D56;Utskriftspris;2;0)*-1)

How should the entry "A4 s/k éi 4.5.2024" be interpreted? I had an order, but nothing was printed? Or if there is no colon and number of sheets, then is it “one copy”? Do you understand? Even a living person cannot understand your recording, but how can you explain this to Calc?

@JohnSUN There is actually a missing number there; it should add a 1 and a semicolon, thus: 4.5.2024: 1; meaning A4 black and white single page: 4.5.2024, 1 page. I’ll edit to correct the error.

Of course, your problem has several solutions. For example, you can try extracting numbers to sum using a complex formula with the REGEX() function, or experiment with FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE()) or come up with an even more complex method.
However, if you clearly understand what exactly needs to be done with the existing string, then it is easier and faster to write your own function in BASIC. For example like this:
Function SplitAndSum(sSourceText As String, sPrefix As String, sSuffix As String) As Double 
Dim aPairs() As String, sPair As String 
Dim aPages() As String 
Dim dResult As Double 
    dResult = 0
    aPairs = Split(sSourceText, sPrefix)
    For Each sPair In aPairs
        aPages = Split(sPair, sSuffix)
        If UBound(aPages) > 0 Then
            dResult = dResult + CLng(aPages(1))
        Else
            dResult = dResult + 1
        EndIf 
    Next sPair
    SplitAndSum = dResult
End Function 

Now a formula like
=-SPLITANDSUM(E56;";";":")*VLOOKUP(D56;Utskriftspris;2;0)
will do exactly the calculation you are asking for in your question.
However, you will greatly simplify the task for both yourself and Calc if you change the order registration form to something like this:



Dato
Antal
Produkt
Pris




05.01.2024
1
A4 s/k to
-0.26


05.04.2024
9
A4 s/k to
-2.34


05.04.2024
1
A4 s/k éi
-0.41


05.04.2024
2
A4 farge to
-20.18


05.05.2024
4
A4 s/k to
-1.04



Just enter your data row by row, day by day, order by order.
A formula like this will help you create a summary table in the form you showed in your question:
{=TEXTJOIN(";";1;IF($E$79:$E$1087=C90;TEXT($C$79:$C$1087;"M.D.YY")&": "&$D$79:$D$1087))}

I get an error message on line 6 (aPairs): ‘BASIC runtime error. The argument is not optional.’ (‘BASIC-køyretidsfeil. Argumentet er ikkje valfritt.’)

This macro does not need to be executed - call it from a formula, as shown immediately after the code =-SPLITANDSUM(E56;";";":")*VLOOKUP(D56;Utskriftspris;2;0)
